# Prevent timeout when opening large files from URL

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am writing a Ruby 1.8.7 script which has to request really large XML files(1 - 5MB) from server which is quite slow(1min30sec for 1MB). The requested file is written to disk.

I set the timeout in my script to some ridiculous amount of seconds, since I really want to get the file, not just move on if it takes too long. Still with the high amount of seconds I keep getting timeouts.

Is there a best practice for this?

right now I use

```
  open(DIR + "" + number + "" + ".xml", 'wb') do |file|
  begin
    status = Timeout::timeout(6000000) do
      file << open(url).read
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error => e
      Rails.logger.info "Timeout for:" + number.to_s
    end
  end
```

now tought timeout was set in seconds which would make `6000000` way more then 1min30sec, but somehow it isn't using my timeout in seconds. Note again that i'm restricted to using Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is problematic. In Ruby 1.9.x, open-uri-extended `open` can take `read_timeout` parameter, which it passes over to http library. But in Ruby 1.8.x, which you're using, this parameter is not available.

So, you need to use net/http directly, call start/get there and set read_timeout to your liking. If you just use the open-uri wrapper, the read_timeout remains 60 seconds, which is shorter than what you want.