# Rails open() times out. How to remove time limit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The following code gives me a `Timeout::Error`

```
open("#{local_file}", 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(remote_file_url).read
end
```

**How can I increase the timeout?** The file to download is big and usually takes more than 2 minutes in the browser.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642364/prevent-timeout-when-opening-large-files-from-url

Comment: I've tried the following but still no avail: ``open("#{coupons_file}", 'wb', {:timeout => 9999999999})`` and also ``open("#{coupons_file}", 'wb', {:read_timeout => 9999999999})`` -- I'm using Ruby 1.9.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice you are opening a remote file "remote_file_url".  I imagine this is where the timeout is coming from.

For starters, I wrote a net/http connection class  that includes timeout code you can use or model.  https://github.com/bf4/Notes/blob/master/code/connection.rb  (I believe the open method is using net/http)

You can also get the response in a block

e.g. something like

```
local_file, url, timeout = 'foo', 'http://www.example.com/index.html', 60
File.open(local_file, 'wb') do |file|
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.open_timeout = timeout 
  http.read_timeout = timeout 
  http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
  http.request_get(uri.request_uri) do |response|
    response.read_body do |segment|
      file.write(segment)
    end
  end
end
```

see http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTPResponse.html and http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html